# Error with reading input in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make the table with the java loop, and I think it's working well.
But I had another errors on reading input. When I type the number and press the button, it should read the information from number, but it keeps make output "null" for the h2 part, and "0" for inside of the cell. I think this code generate null because it can not read the number from input. So I want to know what is the problem in here.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Multiplication table</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
<script src="Generate.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
<header>
<h1>Multiplication Table</h1>
</header>

<article>
  <form>
      <fieldset>
        Enter a number: <input type="number" id="number" />
      </fieldset>
      <fieldset>
        <button type="button" id="button">Generate Times Table</button>
      </fieldset>
  </form>
  <center>
  <h2 id="name"></h2>
  <div id="results">
  <script>
    var submitButton = document.getElementById("button");
    if (submitButton.addEventListener) {
     submitButton.addEventListener("click", generatetable, false); 
     window.addEventListener("load", function() {
        document.getElementById('number').innerHTML = "";
    }, false);
    }
    else if (submitButton.attachEvent)  {
     submitButton.attachEvent("onclick", generatetable);
     window.attachEvent("onload", function() {
        document.getElementById('number').innerHTML = "";
                 });
    } 
    </script>      
</div>
</center>
</article>
</body>
</html>
```

and here is my Generate.js

```
var input = document.getElementById("number");
var table = document.createElement('table'), tr, td, row, cell;
var times = 0;

function generatetable() {
    document.getElementById("name").innerHTML = input + " Times Table";
    for (row = 0; row < 10; row++) {
       tr = document.createElement('tr');
           for (cell = 1; cell <= 3; cell++) {
               times++;
               var result = input * times;
               td = document.createElement('td');
               tr.appendChild(td);
               td.innerHTML = result;
               }
     table.appendChild(tr);
     }
     document.getElementById('results').appendChild(table);
}
```

Comment: Java or Javascript? Change the title!

Comment: Actually, remove it from the title. Tags belong in the tag list, not in the title.

Comment: @TricksfortheWeb Oops! ty

Comment: where is the initialize of tr?, need to put inside the td

Comment: `<tr>`s go into `<tbody>`s, not `<table>`s. You need to create a `<tbody>`, put it into the `<table>` and only then put `<tr>`s into the `<tbody>`.

Comment: @ÁlvaroTouzón Not sure what you mean. `tr` is initialized at this line: `tr = document.createElement('tr');`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were a lot of problems with this, but I got it working.

```js
var submitButton = document.getElementById("button");
if (submitButton.addEventListener) {
  submitButton.addEventListener("click", generatetable, false);
  window.addEventListener("load", function() {
    document.getElementById('number').value = "";
  }, false);
} else if (submitButton.attachEvent) {
  submitButton.attachEvent("onclick", generatetable);
  window.attachEvent("onload", function() {
    document.getElementById('number').value = "";
  });
}

function generatetable() {
  var input = Number(document.getElementById("number").value);
  var table = document.createElement('table'),
    tr, td, row, cell;
  var times = 0;
  document.getElementById("name").innerHTML = input + " Times Table";
  for (row = 0; row < 10; row++) {
    tr = document.createElement('tr');
    for (cell = 1; cell <= 3; cell++) {
      times++;
      var result = input * times;
      td = document.createElement('td');
      td.innerHTML = result;
      tr.appendChild(td);
    }
    table.appendChild(tr);
  }
  document.getElementById('results').appendChild(table);
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1>Multiplication Table</h1>
</header>

<article>
  <form>
    <fieldset>
      Enter a number:
      <input type="number" id="number" />
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
      <button type="button" id="button">Generate Times Table</button>
    </fieldset>
  </form>
  <center>
    <h2 id="name"></h2>
    <div id="results"></div>
  </center>
</article>
```

In addition to getting the value, you also needed to move the `input` variable inside the function, otherwise it would always stay at its initial value, which was 0.

Comment: it works!. I will study this code to understand hows it works. Thank you so much ~_~